# Can't access grub menu by holding shift

Tags: 12.10, grub2

I need to be able to set the nomodeset flag for the system to boot correctly, however pressing and holding shift after the boot screen does not give me access to the Grub menu.  I need to point out this is not a dual boot system.  Is there anyway to do this?  I have also tried pressing space, F1, and F8.

Comment: Repeatedly press the Shift key until you get to GRUB.

Comment: Didn't work.  I resorted to booting into a live CD, installing boot repair, and adding the nomodeset option that way.